# Average loss is 0 when training dataset with darknet yolov4

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, training, yolo

I am currently training a dataset using yolov4 darknet from AlexeyAB Github found here:
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

The dataset I am training is called FishNet Open Images. The dataset has 86,029 images with 5 bounding boxes in each image. It has 34 classes. Currently, I am at 1561 iterations and the training quickly dipped from an avg error loss of around 2000 now to 0.000 rather quickly. Is this supposed to be normal? I feel like I am doing something wrong! I am using around 85% of the images as training set and the other 15% as an validation set.

I have my train.txt and test.txt file correct and my obj.data correct. I changed the annotations to yolo format and configured the .cfg file like below

```
[net]
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=64
width=448
height=448
channels=3
momentum=0.949
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 88000
policy=steps
steps=68800,77400
scales=.1,.1


#cutmix=1
mosaic=1

#:104x104 54:52x52 85:26x26 104:13x13 for 416

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -1,-7

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -1,-10

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -1,-28

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -1,-28

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish

[route]
layers = -1,-16

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=mish
stopbackward=800

##########################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

### SPP ###
[maxpool]
stride=1
size=5

[route]
layers=-2

[maxpool]
stride=1
size=9

[route]
layers=-4

[maxpool]
stride=1
size=13

[route]
layers=-1,-3,-5,-6
### End SPP ###

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = 85

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1, -3

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = 54

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1, -3

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

##########################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=117
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28, 36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146, 142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401
classes=34
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
scale_x_y = 1.2
iou_thresh=0.213
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6
max_delta=5


[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1, -16

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=117
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28, 36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146, 142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401
classes=34
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
scale_x_y = 1.1
iou_thresh=0.213
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6
max_delta=5


[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1, -37

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=117
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 6,7,8
anchors = 12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28, 36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146, 142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401
classes=34
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
scale_x_y = 1.05
iou_thresh=0.213
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6
max_delta=5
```

Here is my obj.data

```
classes = 34
train = data/train.txt 
valid = data/valid.txt
names = data/obj.names
backup = backup/
```

Here is the chart
[image]

Comment: Just try your network once trained, does it gives the correct bounding boxes ?

Answer (score 0):

You have filters = 117 before the Yolo layers. Since you have classes=3 then filters needs to be 24 before the 3 Yolo layers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).